# gevent flask in python

Tags: python, flask

I have a code..and a domain name, I
 like to use this code to display in my domain name

```
from flask import Flask
import gevent.wsgi

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
        return "hello world"
app_server = gevent.wsgi.WSGIServer(('x.y.z.a'), app)
app_server.serve_forever()
```

It shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 10, in <module>
    app_server = gevent.wsgi.WSGIServer(('184.171.170.27'), app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 605, in __init__
    StreamServer.__init__(self, listener, backlog=backlog, spawn=spawn, **ssl_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/server.py", line 48, in __init__
    BaseServer.__init__(self, listener, handle=handle, spawn=spawn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.set_listener(listener)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/server.py", line 70, in set_listener
    BaseServer.set_listener(self, listener)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 80, in set_listener
    self.family, self.address = parse_address(listener)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 323, in parse_address
    raise ValueError('Failed to parse address %r: %s' % (address, sys.exc_info()[1]))
ValueError: Failed to parse address '184.171.170.27': invalid literal 
for int() with base 10: '184.171.170.27'
```

What to do.. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `gevent`'s `baseserver.py` at [their github repo](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/src/gevent/baseserver.py#L379).

The address either needs to be a tuple containing the address and the port, or a string with a `":"` separating the address from the port. I.e, these would be both valid

```
app_server = gevent.wsgi.WSGIServer('x.y.z.a:51515', app)
```

or

```
app_server = gevent.wsgi.WSGIServer(('x.y.z.a', 51515), app)
```

Comment: A nitpick: no need for the redundant parentheses around the address in the first example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..after giving correct code still shows error
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address: ('184.171.170.27', 80)
What to do.. Could you please help me, thank you

Comment: You shouldn't use port 80, it is reserved for standard http traffic.

Comment: Sir, I like to display the output in a website (swarnamala.in, I bought this domain) how can I use the port 80 without error to display output in this domain address.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on your hosting solution. Either you can use something like nginx to serve http traffic on a generic hosting instance, or you can use something python specific, like pythonanywhere.com